# size of textview in scrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, textview

I have a textview in scrollview. in viewDidLoad I change size of textview:

```
description.text = [request valueForKey:@"Description"];
                dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
                dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        CGRect rect      = description.frame;
                        rect.size.height = description.contentSize.height;
                        description.frame = rect;
                    });
                });
```

But when I began to scroll scrollview, size of textView came back to dafault
What`s wrong?

Comment: Have you tried "contentSize"?

Comment: Show the code of delegate of UiScrollView

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? Could you try to run without that?

Comment: When I removed the auto layout checkmark, all of my design is crashed;

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same issue before.
After that I had removed the auto layout checkmark in xib.Its works for me now.Better to use like this.If you take those in xib.
OR
set the content size(value1,value2);

Comment: When I removed the auto layout checkmark, all of my design is crashed;
so what about "set the content size(value1,value2);" how to do this? i have changeble content

Comment: yourscrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width,height)

Comment: I don`t understand how can it help me. I need to touch the button and scroll the scrollview, but textView came back to dafault size.See this
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5Ox7oO5LM4wajZNNTBnOGtKUlU&usp=sharing